# Delete all data from acessdtabase table from vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i want `delete` all data from specific table from access database

I tried following query but it didnot worked
`Query =  "Delete from data`"

Can you give me any code .

```
  PRO = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DJ.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=dj"
    CONNSTRING = PRO
    MYCONNECTION.ConnectionString = CONNSTRING

        MYCONNECTION.Open()


    COMMAND = "Delete * from milkdata where date1='%" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "%'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(COMMAND, MYCONNECTION)

    MsgBox("Record deleted", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

Comment: What is the data type of the date column in the database? If it is Date/Time then you can't use wildcards and if it isn't then it should be because that's the data type dedicated to data and times. Also, you should absolutely not be using the Text of a DateTimePicker. The property of interest is Value.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `LIKE` keyword in your `WHERE` clause since you are using the `%` operator.

Try this: `COMMAND = "Delete * from milkdata where date1 LIKE '%" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "%'"`

instead of your `COMMAND`line.

Comment: If the data represents dates then it should not be text at all and should not support wildcards at all either. It should be stored as binary dates and deleted by range of more than one value must be matched.

Comment: yes you are right, I could only see the `=` with the wildcards, but I should've analyzed the code more thoroughly to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
COMMAND = "Delete * from milkdata where date1='" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString + "'"
```

Or since you're using the `%` operator.

```
COMMAND = "Delete * from milkdata where date1 LIKE '%" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString + "%'"
```